# How do you add a header to a rewritten resource in nginx?

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I am using cakephp and some of my assets (javascript & css) require to be rewritten - for example:

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri\&$args;
expires 1M;
access_log off;
add_header Pragma "public";
add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

However the headers I add in this location block are lost when I do a rewrite. Rewrites in Cakephp requires the index.php file, so the try_files directive above eventually takes me to this location:

```
location ~* \.(?:php)$ { ... }
```

The resources then receives only headers set in that location. This is not what I want - I want to be able to rewite the asset and apply the correct headers ... despite looking everywhere online, I cannot find out how to prevent a rewrite from changes the resource's headers.

Answer (score 0):

Should work by setting your webroot to the document root.

Check the configuration below

```
root /home/your_user/your_app/webroot;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

**To add header to resource**

```
location ~* \.(type|type1|type2|type3)$ {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html

Comment: My document root is already set to the webroot. It still doesn't allow me to specify a header when an asset is rewritten.